# Using the Google APIs with OAuth 2.0 for gmail login in iPhone

Tags: ios, oauth, gmail, google-api

I have found a services from Google which provides to access to `Google APIs` for various Google Services. I could set up a project in iPhone and create API access for iOS applications (via `OAuth2.0`) and native applications. I wanted to use the native API for my iPhone app. It API gives me  email,fullname,firstname,lastname,google_id,gender,dob,profile_image. How do I use these in my iPhone Application, Any sample apps, snippets available?

Please help me.

Here is my code :

```
-(void) loadGmail_Login
{
    NSString *keychainItemName = nil;
    if ([self shouldSaveInKeychain]) {
        keychainItemName = kKeychainItemName;
    }

    // For GTM applications, the scope is available as
    NSString *scope = @"http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/";

    // ### Important ###
    // GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch is not designed to be reused. Make a new
    // one each time you are going to show it.

    // Display the autentication view.
    GTMOAuthAuthentication *auth;
    auth = [GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName];

    GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch *viewController = [[[GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch alloc]
                                                    initWithScope:scope
                                                    language:nil
                                                    appServiceName:keychainItemName
                                                    delegate:self
                                                    finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)] autorelease];

    // You can set the title of the navigationItem of the controller here, if you want.
    // Optional: display some html briefly before the sign-in page loads
    NSString *html = @"<html><body bgcolor=silver><div align=center>Loading sign-in page...</div></body></html>";
    [viewController setInitialHTMLString:html];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

}

- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch *)viewController
      finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuthAuthentication *)auth
                 error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error != nil)
    {
        // Authentication failed (perhaps the user denied access, or closed the
        // window before granting access)
        NSLog(@"Authentication error: %@", error);
        NSData *responseData = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"data"]; // kGTMHTTPFetcherStatusDataKey
        if ([responseData length] > 0) {
            // show the body of the server's authentication failure response
            NSString *str = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
            NSLog(@"%@", str);
        }

        [self setAuthentication:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        // save the authentication object
        [self setAuthentication:auth];

        // Just to prove we're signed in, we'll attempt an authenticated fetch for the
        // signed-in user
        [self doAnAuthenticatedAPIFetch];
    }

}

- (void)doAnAuthenticatedAPIFetch
{
    NSString *urlStr;

    // Google Contacts feed
    //
    //    https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo
    urlStr = @"http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/thin";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [mAuth authorizeRequest:request];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                         returningResponse:&response
                                                     error:&error];
    if (data) {
        // API fetch succeeded
        NSString *str = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
        NSLog(@"API response: %@", str);

        GGCXml_Adaptor *localAlphabetXMLParser = [[GGCXml_Adaptor alloc] init];
        [localAlphabetXMLParser processBooksXML:data];
        [localAlphabetXMLParser release];
        //        [self updateUI];



    } else {
        // fetch failed
        NSLog(@"API fetch error: %@", error);
    }
}

- (void)setAuthentication:(GTMOAuthAuthentication *)auth {
    [mAuth autorelease];
    mAuth = [auth retain];
}
```

Comment: Hi,I am not sure what you are looking to do. From the data (name, email, dob..) provided by google, you can have a user profile page to display but essentially its really down to your app design and idea. Should need to further clarification, Google have a pretty good documentation on OAuth https://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/wiki/Introduction

Comment: Please explain exactly what you expect..

Answer (score 1):

First you will need to get token from Google API, For this 1st step you will have to follow this tutorial and in the end of this link there is whole source code for iOS for getting token from google API

http://technogerms.com/login-with-google-using-oauth-2-0-for-ios-xcode-objective-c/

Then in the next step you have to send that token to Google API to request user Data, I just needed the first step So I am sharing my searchings

Comment: Please summarize the link in the post - links go dead and it would be good if you answer was useful to the next people.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this Tutorial and Source code Link

.. It's works fine for me.

**1. Tutorial Reference:** http://technogerms.com/login-with-google-using-oauth-2-0-for-ios-xcode-objective-c/

**2. Api Reference :** https://code.google.com/apis/console/

**3. Source code:** https://github.com/emysa341/Login-with-gmail-google-g--using-oath-2.0-protocol/archive/master.zip

Comment: tutorial link is dead and it is not summarized in the reply

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help anybody else
Follow the below steps to integrate gmail with your application .

**1.Add following classes to you project .**

GTMHTTPFetcher.h , GTMHTTPFetcher.m ,GTMOAuth2Authentication.h, GTMOAuth2Authentication.m,GTMOAuth2SignIn.h,GTMOAuth2SignIn.m,GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h,GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.m,GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.xib,SBJSON.h , SBJSON.m

you will get these classes here : https://github.com/jonmountjoy/Force.com-iOS-oAuth-2.0-Example

**Note** : if you are working under ARC Environment then you have to disable the ARC for following files :
GTMHTTPFetcher.m , GTMOAuth2Authentication.m , GTMOAuth2SignIn.m, GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.m

To disable ARC for source files in Xcode 4, select the project and the target in Xcode. Under the target "Build Phases" tab, expand the Compile Sources build phase, select the library source files, then press Enter to open an edit field, and type -fno-objc-arc as the compiler flag for those files.

**2. add the following frameworks**

```
security.framework , systemConfiguration.framework
```

**3. Register your app to google api console …. here :** https://code.google.com/apis/console

Then go to ApiAccess section , create client id for iOS app .
 then you will get clientID, ClientSecret and RedirectUrl

****4. Now it's time for coding  . . . .****
create a signIn button in your controller and set the action for that . Here when the user click the button SignInGoogleButtonClicked method gets called .

```
//import GTMOAuth2Authentication , GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch

#define GoogleClientID    @"paster your client id"
#define GoogleClientSecret @"paste your client secret"
#define GoogleAuthURL   @"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"
#define GoogleTokenURL  @"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"

-(void) SignInGoogleButtonClicked
{

 NSURL * tokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString:GoogleTokenURL];

    NSString * redirectURI = @"urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";

    GTMOAuth2Authentication * auth;

    auth = [GTMOAuth2Authentication authenticationWithServiceProvider:@"google"
                                                             tokenURL:tokenURL
                                                          redirectURI:redirectURI
                                                             clientID:GoogleClientID
                                                         clientSecret:GoogleClientSecret];

    auth.scope = @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me";

    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch * viewcontroller = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithAuthentication:auth
                                                                                                authorizationURL:[NSURL URLWithString:GoogleAuthURL]
                                                                                                keychainItemName:@"GoogleKeychainName" delegate:self
                                                                                                finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES];

}



//this method is called when authentication finished

- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch * )viewController finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication * )auth error:(NSError * )error
{

    if (error != nil) {

        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Authorizing with Google"
                                                         message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                        delegate:nil
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {

         UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert !"
                                                         message:@"success"
                                                        delegate:nil
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
}
```

Comment: Hello riyaz..is it possible to share posts using this oAuth protocol method.please reply asap

Comment: i have done basic authentication and basic info fetch , i dnt have any idea about posts sharing ...